# Which babel file is React including in that CDN script src?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

In the demo html page downloaded from the 'Trying Out React' page, they use the following CDN to bring in babel.js:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Seems like React knows to automatically use this library.

But if I've installed babel using `npm install babel-cli` Where can I find this 'babel.js' file?

```
<script src="node_modules/babel-cli/[babel.js?]"></script>
```

Am I thinking about this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you now need to compile the script(s) you're using which require Babel, as described in the Usage guide: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

You may need to use the "--out-file" to reference later in your HTML file.

Comment: When I use the CDN script, the React scripts work fine, otherwise, it fails to parse my JSX. Any idea which file this mysterious babel.min.js corresponds to in the babel-cli node module?

Comment: I think the CDN script may be a live transpiler; however in your app you will want to use Babel to build your JSX (and ES6) files into a bundle.js file.  It's worth checking out documentation and tutorials on how to do this. Here is one example: https://www.codementor.io/tamizhvendan/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack-du107r9zr

Comment: Glad to hear! Good luck with your React endeavors :)